# Chef knife ssh sed command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, chef-infra

I run a sed command with knife ssh:

```
knife ssh 'name:mynode' 'sudo sed -i 's/https:\/\/test1.mydomain.com/https:\/\/test2.mydomain.com/g' /etc/chef/1.rb' -x myuser ./mypem.pem
```

I got an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'
```

If I try

```
knife ssh 'name:mynode' "sudo sed -i 's/https:\/\/test1.mydomain.com/https:\/\/test2.mydomain.com/g' /etc/chef/1.rb" -x myuser ./mypem.pem

Error:

sed: can't read ./mypem.pem: No such file or directory
```

Also if I try

```
knife ssh 'name:mynode' "'sudo sed -i 's/https:\/\/test1.mydomain.com/https:\/\/test2.mydomain.com/g' /etc/chef/1.rb'" -x myuser ./mypem.pem
Error:
bash: sudo sed -i s/https://test1.mydomain.com/https://test2.mydomain.com/g /etc/chef/1.rb: No such file or directory
```

the command works from the machine:

```
sudo sed -i 's/https:\/\/test1.mydomain.com/https:\/\/test2.mydomain.com/g' /etc/chef/1.rb
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: use double quotes "" around your whole command or escape the singles quote around the sed script., as is you're ending the quotes, pasting characters and reopening the quotes.

Comment: I tried 
knife ssh 'name:mynode' "'sudo sed -i 's/https:\/\/test1.mydomain.com/https:\/\/test2.mydomain.com/g' /etc/chef/1.rb'" -x myuser ./mypem.pem
and i got an error
bash: sudo sed -i s/https://test1.mydomain.com/https://test2.mydomain.com/g /etc/chef/1.rb: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you launching the knife command from windows or linux ?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to manage the whole file as a template within a recipe ? This kind of usage is absolutely against what chef is made for.

Comment: launching from ubuntu

Comment: I want to replace the server url to all my nodes

Comment: Have a look at the [chef-client](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client) cookbook, specially the config recipe which can manage that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create recipe and run it with knife ssh

```
bash 'sed' do
  code <<-EOH
    sudo sed -i 's,https://test1.mydomain.com,https://test2.mydomain.com,g' /etc/chef/1.rb
    EOH
end
```